# Issue installing hotwire gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hotwire-rails

Each time after adding the hotwire gem to my gemfile, I always appear to get these responses in my terminal.
When attempting to mess around with hotwire it gives me the impression this is causing issues. New to rails so I am sorry if I a missing something simple, but havent been able to find anything else on this online yet.

Looking for a solution on how to get passed this so I can start working with hotwire.

[image: hotwire errors]

Comment: rails 7 has "hotwire" configured by default and also `hotwire-rails` gem has been obsolete since rails 7 release.

Comment: to add to @Alex, see: https://github.com/hotwired/hotwire-rails how to move on. Hotwire is for now Turbo + Stimulus